# Mobilefirst 7.1 wlInitOptions return undefined with WL.Client.Init

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

We have Mobile hybrid app running on MFP 7.1.0.00.20170627-0807. Our  wlInitOptions is as below:

```
    var wlInitOptions = {


    autoHideSplash : false,
    showIOS7StatusBar : false,
    onSuccess : function (response) {
        console.log(" wlInitOptions onSuccess :" +  JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    onFailure : function (error) {
        alert("System Error: Failed to connect !!");
    },

    onConnectionFailure: function (error) {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                "System Error: Server connection error",
                error,
                [{text: "Close", handler: null}]
        );
    },

    onUserInstanceAccessViolation : function (error) {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                "System Error: User Access not available",
                error,
                [{text: "Close", handler: null}]
        );
    },

    timeout: 10000,
    onRequestTimeout : function (error) {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                "System Error: Request Timeout",
                error,
                [{text: "Close", handler: null}]
        );
    },

    onErrorRemoteDisableDenial : function (message, downloadLink) {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                appStoreUpdateTitle,
                message,
                [{text: notNowButton, handler: function() {WL.App.close();}},
                 {text: downloadNewVersionBtn, handler: function() {WL.App.openURL(downloadLink, "_blank");}}]
        );
    },

};


if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
        console.log(" wlInitOptions 1 :" +  JSON.stringify(WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions)));

    }, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
        WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
        console.log(" wlInitOptions 2 :" +  JSON.stringify(WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions)));

    });
}



};
```

I'm trying to identify what is the response we get from success init. However, the log is always comes as undefined even though our app is working as expected.

How would I know what is the response content and why it is undefined.

The reason behind this is to track the failure of the init call so we can capture the log and the exact response that caused the failure.

Logs:

```
2017-07-26 12:56:04.281 ManulifeBankMobile[19779:517705] wlInitOptions onSuccess :undefined
2017-07-26 12:56:04.281 ManulifeBankMobile[19779:517705] wlInitOptions 1 :undefined
2017-07-26 12:56:04.281 ManulifeBankMobile[19779:517705] wlInitOptions 2 :undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WL.Client.init()` function is an asynchronous void function - it doesn't return anything. You can use the `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks to react to overall success or failure of the `WL.Client.init()` call, respectively. These callbacks, however, are not passed a reference to the actual response. If you want to respond to specific failure scenarios, you can specify a number of additional failure callback functions in your options object. These callbacks will be invoked when the associated error scenario occurs:

- `onUnsupportedVersion`
- `onRequestTimeout`
- `onUnsupportedBrowser`
- `onDisabledCookies`
- `onUserInstanceAccessViolation`
- `onErrorRemoteDisableDenial`
- `onErrorAppVersionAccessDenial`

Note that the general `onFailure` callback will be invoked in every failure case.

See the [WL.Client.init() documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html#init) for more info